# Il contrario di "verbalmente" è "per iscritto"?

Tags: adverbs

In un contesto scritto, quale può essere il contrario di "verbalmente"?

Ad esempio:
"Come da accordi presi verbalmente, si decide di..."

può diventare:

"Come da accordi presi per iscritto, si decide di..."?

È corretta la forma "per iscritto", è ancora utilizzata/utilizzabile o è troppo desueta?

Comment: La *i prostetica* è in generale desueta e pochi scrivono (o dicono) *in Isvizzera* o *per ischerzo*. La locuzione *per iscritto* però può considerarsi cristallizzata.

Comment: Un'alternativa comune nel linguaggio formale/legale è *in forma scritta*. Per esempio, *eventuali modifiche al contratto devono essere approvate in forma scritta dalle parti*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La forma **per iscritto** è assolutamente corretta, specialmente se fa da contraltare agli avverbi **verbalmente** o **oralmente**.

Su questo [sito di sinonimi e contrari](http://www.sinonimi-contrari.it/mettere+per+iscritto/) viene proposto il verbo *verbalizzare* come alternativa a *mettere per iscritto*, ma questo termine contiene in sè un significato più formale, come possiamo vedere da questo [dizionario online](http://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Italiano/parola/v/verbalizzare.aspx?query=verbalizzare)

**verbalizzare** [ver-ba-liʒ-ʒà-re] (verbalìzzo)

1. **verbo transitivo** *[burocratico]* Mettere a verbale: v. le dichiarazioni di un testimone
2. **verbo intransitivo** *(ausiliario avere)* Compilare, stendere il verbale

Spero di aver risposto al tuo dubbio!